# shortcut for "find all" in SublimeText2

Tags: sublimetext2

When i double click on any word, ST highlights all other such words in file. Are there any combination to put cursor on each such word so that i can edit them at once (like after ctrl+f and then alt+enter - "find all")?

Comment: something like ctrl+D several time ?

Comment: yes, like ctrl+d maximum times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ctrl + D several time or Alt +F3 :)

Comment: Alt+f3 is s system combination in Ubuntu's KDE that opens window dialog with maximize/minimize/cloze/move to desktop (((

Comment: Rebinded Alt+f3 in KDE and now it works just fine in ST2. Thanx!

Comment: @SET stuck at the same issue how did you rebind?

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia, I don't remember now but I believe it somewhere in `control center` -> `keyboard shortcuts`

Answer (score 1):

On a Mac, but I do CTRL + COMMAND + G to hightlight all the instances of the word.